# ¿Por qué «señor» evolucionó a «so» para reforzar lo negativo, pero se mantuvo como «señor» para reforzar lo positivo?

Tags: etimología, historia, lingüística

En frases negativas es relativamente habitual el uso de «so» como refuerzo, por ejemplo en *«¡Deja de tocar, **so** manazas!»*.

Si consultamos el significado en el DLE:

> [**so**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Y38uhep)
>   Contracc. de *seó*.
>   1. adv. U. para potenciar el significado del adjetivo o del sustantivo al que antecede, generalmente con sentido despectivo.

Vemos que viene de [*seó*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xcb6mEb), y éste a su vez de [*seor*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XcbtfmF), y éste, finalmente, de *señor*:

> [**señor, ra**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XcBNzxH)
>   18. adj. coloq. Antepuesto a algunos nombres, sirve para encarecer su entidad. *Se hizo una señora herida. Se compró una señora casa.*

Que, curiosamente, se puede usar exactamente para lo mismo que «so», pero en frases positivas.

¿Por qué esta evolución de una palabra a otra para significados peyorativos y no para los positivos, cuando el significado era el mismo?

Comment: Una señora pregunta. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se me ocurre que al ser *so* una degradación de *señor*, puede haber sido usado en el pasado por las personas más humildes o incultas (como ocurre en Chile con las palabras "ño" e "iñor", que forman parte del estereotipo del campesino bruto).

Entonces los esnobs del pasado tal vez usaron el *so* con un valor peyorativo despectivo. Por ejemplo, puedo suponer que *señor boticario* es más prestigioso que *so boticario*. Y habiéndose convertido en una palabra negativa y más o menos sarcástica, no sería difícil que sirviera para intensificar lo negativo, dejándose "señor" para intensificar lo positivo.

Answer (score 9):

Lo que pasó con *so* fue, posiblemente (no puedo corroborarlo), que conforme se fue corrompiendo la palabra se fue vaciando de su significado original para significar otra cosa diferente.

Se nota, eso sí, que su origen es el que es dado que *so* se puede reemplazar por *señor* y la frase mantiene su sentido, aunque el insulto posterior pierde fuerza (como es el caso de *so mequetrefe* y *señor mequetrefe*), y en algunos casos incluso pasa de ser un insulto a ser un apelativo neutro (como es el caso de *so payaso* y *señor payaso*).

Buscando en el CORDE apariciones de *seor*, la primera etapa de la conversión, encuentro una mayoría de casos en los que se usa como una simple corrupción de *señor* (*seor leyente*, *seor hidalgo*, *seor Antoñico*, *seor alguacil*, *seor doctor*, etc.), y muy pocos casos en los que se use ante un insulto (*seor mequetrefe* [c1637]).

De la segunda etapa de la conversión encuentro menos casos, pero parece que ya hay menos desigualdad entre el número de casos positivos (*seó licenciado*, *seó sacristán*) y negativos (*seó trasto* [1828-1870]).

Tal vez una prueba de este proceso de pérdida del significado original se encuentra en que la palabra *seor* todavía tenía su versión femenina en *seora*, mientra que *seó* ya no tiene versión femenina y se usa exclusivamente en masculino. Esto debió ayudar definitivamente al vaciado del significado previo. Podemos comprobar esto en las ediciones históricas del diccionario:

- La palabra *seor* aparece ya en el diccionario de autoridades (tomo S-Z, 1739). Equivale completamente a *señor* y es de uso familiar. Su versión femenina, *seora*, aparece (curiosamente) por primera vez en el DLE en 1884.
- La palabra *seó* con el significado de *seor* aparece en el DLE por primera vez en 1852. No se le conoce ninguna contrapartida femenina.
- La palabra *so* obviamente aparece desde muy antiguo con su significado como preposición (equivalente a *bajo*), e incluso como interjección para hacer detener a los caballos ya desde el de Autoridades. Sin embargo, su significado como contracción de *seó* aparece en el DLE en 1899, especificando que "se usa solamente seguido de adjetivos despectivos con los cuales se increpa a alguna persona".

Así, la línea temporal según el DLE sería *seor* (1739) → *seó* (1852) → *so* (1899). Se ve que ya a finales del siglo XIX se usaba *so* con el mismo fin que hoy día.

> *Hubo ademanes violentos, y un cuerpo cayó... Llegaba en esto corriendo otra figura humana, que venía también del hotel por la escalera, e interponiéndose, se inclinó para recoger a Lucía. Miranda accionaba, y con voz ronca, estrangulada y tartajosa de rabia, decía, dando al diablo todo su porte cortesano:
>
>   —Fuera de ahí, so tío... so entrometido... ¿usted que... qué tiene que ver?... Yo la abo... la abofeteo, porque pu... pu... puedo y me da la gana... Soy su marido. Si no se va usted, le parto por la mitad... le abro en canal...*
>
> Emilia Pardo Bazán, *Un viaje de novios*, 1881 (España).

Otros ejemplos encontrados en textos del siglo XIX: *so indecentes*, *so [tunante](http://dle.rae.es/?id=auH5lYw)*, *so pillo*, *so [tía](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZoWtFfy)* (según el DLE, usada en femenino *tía* puede significar "prostituta"), *so [alcornoque](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1ea0i3k)*, *so bandido*, *so [calzonudos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6t0tahJ)*, *so animal*, *so pringoso*, *so [maula](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Oe49rmt)*, *so [espantajo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GU6k7Uu)*, *so [mamarracho](http://dle.rae.es/?id=O5tvhB7)*, *so [peal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SF5U7xU)*...

Comment: Pues ahí tenemos incluso _zopenco_ de _so penco_ (poco trabajador), tal y como se expica en: [La vida empuja a la lengua: de señora a señoro](https://verne.elpais.com/verne/2018/10/05/articulo/1538748293_739942.html)