# Formas reducidas de señor, -ra

Tags: sinónimos, contracciones

La RAE nota unas formas reducidas de *señor, señora*:

- [**seor(a)**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=XcbtfmF) → [**seó**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Xcb6mEb) → [so](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Y38uhep)
- señorita → [seño](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Xc805A7)
- [iñor(a)](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=i%C3%B1or) → [ñor](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QlO0Odn)([a](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=%C3%B1or))
- [ño](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QlBeESx), señá → [ña](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QjyjUqy)

Entiendo que *seño* es una forma infantil que usan los estudiantes para referir a una maestra (y [aparentemente](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=se%C3%B1o) una forma afectuosa general en Ecuador, Bolivia y el norte de Colombia).

Y el diccionario de americanismos dice que [*ño*](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=%C3%B1o) y [*ña*](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=%C3%B1a) son formas obsoletas americanas, que hoy en día solo se usan en el habla rural de unos países, y *ña* «especialmente para mujeres solteras de mucha edad». Es un caso similar para *ñor* e *iñor*.

Pero jamás he oído *seó, seor*. ¿Dónde se usan? ¿Son sinónimos exactos para señor/señora, o solo se usan en ciertas circunstancias?

Comment: He escuchado que en México se dice "señito" a las señoras de cariño, sin embargo no están definidas en la RAE.

Answer (score 6):

Como se explica en [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21580/13628), *seó* y *seor/a/es/as* (en adelante ***seó**** para abreviar) son corrupciones de *señor, señora* que se dieron hace tiempo en registros de habla vulgares.

> ¿Dónde se usan?

Hoy en día, en ninguna parte*, me temo. Si buscas en [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) o en [CREA](http://corpus.rae.es/creanet.html) o en [CORPES](http://web.frl.es/CORPES/view/inicioExterno.view), verás que los usos de *seó** ya en el siglo pasado era escasísimos, y siempre circunscritos a transcripciones de obras anteriores o a diálogos en los que se intenta hacer ver que quien así habla pertenece a un estrato social más bajo.

<sub>* Entendido como que no hay zonas específicas donde se siga usando de manera habitual, sin perjuicio de algunos usos testimoniales aquí y allá por parte, imagino, de personas de avanzada edad.</sub>

> ¿Son sinónimos exactos para *señor/señora*, o solo se usan en ciertas circunstancias?

Ambas cosas :)
Son sinónimos exactos: *seora Paquita* es exactamente lo mismo que *señora Paquita*, *seó alcalde* lo mismo que *señor alcalde*, y *seor negocio* igual que *señor negocio*; pero no se usan en las mismas circunstancias, por lo indicado arriba (registro anticuado y vulgar).

NOTA: Entiendo la pregunta como referida a uso "vivo", y en ese sentido es mi respuesta. Obviamente en literatura se sigue usando siempre que el contexto lo requiera.